# How to copy table index to another table in ado.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am using SqlBulkCopy in ado.net to copy one table to another. The code is:

```
    using (sourceConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OTPTestConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        sourceConnection.Open();

        // Get data from the source table as a SqlDataReader.
        SqlCommand commandSourceData = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + sourceTableName, sourceConnection);
        SqlDataReader reader = commandSourceData.ExecuteReader();

        using (destConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLExpressDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            destConnection.Open();

            // Perform bulk copy
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destConnection))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destTableName;

                // Write from the source to the destination.
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
...
```

It works fine but can not copy primary key index in original table to new table. I'd like how to do it in Ado.net. Thanks.

Comment: there is no errors? If key index is key also in table that you are copying to, then how it is possible that you can copy data withut this key? Or/and, 100% that index was not automatic increase?  like 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc

Comment: I need index not automatic increase because old table index is not. If use sql command "Insert select ", index will be copied too, but it needs to enter the column names in the command.

Comment: Did you try to specify SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity for your SqlBulkCopy object?

Comment: Yes, I find that already. You can post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out by using SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity. The code is

```
        SqlBulkCopyOptions options = SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity;
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destConnection.ConnectionString, options))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destTableName;
                // Write from the source to the destination.
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
        }
```